# Find largest stopping time such that the stopped process is a submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t=0,1,...,T},P$) be a
> filtered probability space. Let $X=(X_t)_{t=0,1...,T}$ an adapted
> process (to $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_0,...,X_t)$) that is integrable
> (i. e. $E(|X_t|)<\infty$), $t=0,1,...,T$. What is the largest stopping
> time $\tau: \Omega \to \{0,1,...,T\}$ such that the stopped process
> $X^{\tau}$ is a submartingale?

**My ideas**

- I know that the stopped process is also adapted
- I know about the Optional Sampling theorem.

"largest" stopping time means that for every other stopping time $\tau'$ for which $X^{\tau'}$ is a submartingale we have $P(\tau'\leq \tau')=1$, so it is "almost certain" the case.

I was given a hint elsewhere to look at the [Doob decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_decomposition_theorem). But looking at the doob decomposition, how can I derive the largest stopping time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
**Hint :** By Doob's decomposition, we know that for all times $t$, we can write
$$X_t = M_t + A_t $$

Where $M$ is a martingale and $A$ is integrable, predictable and satisfies $A_0 = 0$. Now let $\tau$ be any stopping time : by definition, $X^\tau$ is a submartingale if and only $\mathbb E[X_{t+1\wedge\tau}\mid \mathcal F_t]\ge X_{t\wedge\tau} $, that is, if and only if

$$\mathbb E[M_{t+1\wedge\tau}\mid \mathcal F_t] + \mathbb E[A_{t+1\wedge\tau}\mid \mathcal F_t] = \cancel{M_{t\wedge\tau}}+ \mathbb E[A_{t+1\wedge\tau}\mid \mathcal F_t]\ge \cancel{M_{t\wedge\tau}} + A_{t\wedge\tau}, \ \  \forall t\in\{ 0,\ldots,T-1 \} $$

Where we have used linearity of conditional expectation and the [optional stopping theorem](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/20/optional-sampling/).

Now because $A$ is predictable, it holds that for all $s\le t+1$, $A_s$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable. This implies that the above sufficient and necessary condition for $X^\tau$ to be a submartingale can equivalently be restated as
$$ A_{t+1\wedge \tau} \ge A_{t\wedge\tau}, \ \  \forall t\in\{ 0,\ldots,T-1 \} \tag1 $$

Can you find a stopping time which makes this condition hold ? (And can you check that it is indeed the largest such stopping time ?)

---

**Added :** Ok, let me give a solution based on my hint above and what I wrote in the comments. But before that, another (hopefully) "intuitive" explanation of how $\tau$ may be found : Doob's theorem tells us that we can write $X$ as a sum of a martingale $M$ and some arbitrary predictable process $A$. If we want $X^\tau$ to be a submartingale, that means we want $X^\tau$ to be nondecreasing "in expectation". However, $M$ is "constant", so really, **the only way to make $X^\tau$ a submartingale is to pick $\boldsymbol\tau$ such that $A^\tau$ is almost surely non-decreasing**.

Well, so far it seems like I just restated $(1)$ in a very unprecise fashion, but think about it : what stopping time (which can involve **all the $A_t$'s up to $A_{t+1}$**) can guarantee that $A^\tau$ is non-decreasing ? That would precisely be "*the first instant $t$ where the sequence $(A_t)$ starts to decrease*", or equivalently "*the last instant $t$ up to which $(A_t)$ is non-decreasing*". Yes, it's really that simple ! More formally, we can let $\tau$ be defined as
$$\tau(\omega) := \begin{cases}\inf\{t=0,\ldots, T-1 : A_{t+1}(\omega)< A_t(\omega)\},\ \text{ if the inf is attained},\\
T \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
(that splitting in two cases is purely a technicality due to the fact that $A_{T+1}$ is not defined.)

If you followed the above explanation, you may have an intuitive idea of why $\tau$ *has* to be the solution to our problem, but we still need to check that formally :

- That $\tau$ is a stopping time follows from the predictability of $A$ : indeed the event $\{\tau=t\}=\{A_{t+1}<A_t\}\cap\{A_{s+1}\ge A_s, 0\le s \le t-1\}$ is given by the intersection of finitely many events of $\mathcal F_t$ and thus belongs itself in $\mathcal F_t$ (I encourage you to double check that all of these sets are indeed in $\mathcal F_t$)
- That $X^\tau$ is a submartingale should be clear from the definition of $\tau$, but let's prove it anyway : as we said, $X^\tau$ is a submartingale iff $A^\tau$ is a.s. increasing. But for any $t$, either $t\ge \tau(\omega)$ in which case $A_{t+1\wedge\tau}=A_{t\wedge\tau} =A_{\tau(\omega)}$, or $t<\tau(\omega)$, in which case by definition of $\tau$ we have $A_{t+1\wedge\tau}=A_{t+1}\ge A_{t} =A_{t\wedge\tau}$. So $X^\tau$ is indeed a submartingale.
- Lastly, we check that $\tau$ is maximal : indeed, assume for the sake of contradiction that there exits another stopping time $\theta$ such that $X^\theta$ is a submartingale and $\theta \ge \tau +1 $ on a positive measure set (this necessarily implies $\tau\le T-1$, as $X$ is not defined otherwise). Then, because $X^\theta$ is a submartingale, we have for all $\omega$ belonging in this positive measure event that for $t \in[\tau(\omega),\theta(\omega)-1]$ :
  $$A_{t+1\wedge\theta(\omega)} \ge  A_{t\wedge\theta(\omega)} \implies A_{t +1}\ge A_{t}. $$ Which contradicts the definition of $\tau$ and thus implies that $\tau$ is indeed the largest stopping time which makes $X^\tau$ a submartingale.

Hope that helps !

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I suppose $(t+1)\, \land \tau:=\min(t+1,\tau)$. But what do we know about $A$ that would make finding $\tau$ obvious?

Comment: Yes, $a\wedge b$ is a shorthand for $\min(a,b)$ (quite common notation). I give you two more hints : 1) a stopping time $\tau$ is a $[0,T]$ valued random variable such that $\{\tau = t\} \in\mathcal F_t $. Here, since $A$ is predictable, $\sigma(A_{t+1}) \in \mathcal F_t$, so you can take $\tau$ such that  $\{\tau = t\}$ depends on $A_0,A_1,\ldots,A_{t+1}$. 2) stopping times are often of the form "the first time $t(\omega)$ such that *something* happens". What "something" (which will depend on the $A_0,\ldots,A_{t+1}$) would work here ?

Comment: $\tau=\inf\{t\in [0,T] : A_t\geq 0\}\,\land T$?

Comment: @Analysis see my edit :)

Comment: Thanks a million!